# How to make a new UILabel every time a UIButton is pressed?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uilabel

I want to add a function to my program so that a new label is made every time a button is pressed and I thought the best way to do this is to have a variable sized array of type UILabel and add an element to the array (a UILabel) every time the button is pressed, however, I am not sure how to do this.

I have tried:

```
var consoleLbl = [UILabel] ()
@IBAction func pushButton(sender: UIButton) {
    consoleLbl[0] = UILabel()
    consoleLbl.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:10, height:10)
}
```

However, I get the following error:
"Value of optional type 'UILabel?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type 'UILabel'"
and if I add a "?" or "!" as it suggests, I get the error: 
"Value of type 'UILabel' has no subscripts"

Comment: your question is not clear though. What exactly you want ? want to create label and add to array or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 var consoleLbl = [UILabel]()
 var y = 0
 @IBAction func pushButton(sender: UIButton) {
     let lbl = UILabel() 
     lbl.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:y, width:10, height:10)
     lbl.text = "\(y)"
     consoleLbl.append(lbl)
     view.addSubview(lbl)  
     y += 20
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var consoleLbl = [UILabel]()
 var x = Int()
 x = 0

 @IBAction func pushButton(sender: UIButton) {
     let lbl = UILabel() 
     lbl.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:10, width:10, height:10)
     lbl.text = "\(x)"
     consoleLbl.append(lbl)
     view.addSubview(lbl)  
     x += 20 // 10 is width & 10 is gap between two label
 }
```